# Visual Studio 2017 - Link C++ Shared Library with C++ Library in Android

Tags: android, c++, visual-studio

I've an Android project in Visual Studio Community 2017 (Version of June 18, 2018 - 15.7.4) with two C++ libraries which include themselsvs each another C++ library.

The project structure looks like:

- Project1: Android
- Project2: lib1 (C++)
- Project3: -> lib1.1 (C++ referenced in lib1)
- Project4: lib2 (C++ referenced in lib1)
- Project5:  -> lib2.1 (C++ referenced in lib2)

---

- lib1, lib2 are of Visual Studio prject type: `Dynamic Shared Library (Android)` which can be found in `Visual C++` -> `Cross Plattform` -> `Android`
- lib1.1, lib2.1 are of Visual Studio prject type: `Shared Items Project` which can be found in `Visual C++` -> `General`

[image: Visual Studio 2017 New Project dialog]

In the Android project I load them like

```
static
{
    System.loadLibrary("lib2");
    System.loadLibrary("lib1");
}
```

The compiled App worked as long as I used only lib1. As soon as I referenced lib2 in lib1 and used code of lib2.1 the following error occurs at startup at the line:

```
System.loadLibrary("lib2");
```

The following error is shown in the Logcat of Android:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "C:\MyProject\MyProject.Mobile\bin\Android\Debug\ARM\lib1.so" not found
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:372)
....
```

It seems that Visual Studio compiles the wrong path into the app. Why would the lib1 be searched on my developing machine but not on the phone itself.

Any hint what is wrong?

Comment: Looks like you're having the same problem as myself. My observation is that this is a bug in the build system of Visual Studio. I've reported this to Microsoft, see https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/279225/linking-a-c-dynamic-library-for-android-to-another.html